# Performing normal or uniform initializations on Float tensors result in only zeros

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import torch
pytorchGPUDirectCreateWEmpty = torch.empty(size=(20000000, 128), dtype=torch.float, device='cuda', requires_grad=False, pin_memory=False).uniform_(-1, 1)
pytorchGPUDirectCreateWEmpty
```

results in

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]], device='cuda:0')
```

and

```
import torch
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
u_embeddings = torch.nn.Embedding(20000000, 128, padding_idx=None, max_norm=None, norm_type=2.0, scale_grad_by_freq=False, sparse=False, _weight=None)
u_embeddings.weight.data.uniform_(-1, 1)
u_embeddings.weight.data
```

results in

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

If I initialize with `double` instead of `float` and the initialization works fine. I could convert to float later, but I am working with limited memory and unable to initialize a double first before converting.

Why is the initialization not working for float tensors?